# About $\sin 2\theta+\sqrt{3}\cos 2\theta=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$0\leq\theta<2\pi$. When $\theta$ satisfies $\sin 2\theta+\sqrt{3}\cos 2\theta=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, solve $\alpha+\beta$ ( $\alpha$:= minimum $\theta$, $\beta$:= maximum $\theta$). From the graph of $y=\sin(2\theta+\frac{\pi}{3}$), I think the answer is $\frac{11}{6}\pi$ but can't prove.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin 2\theta = \sqrt 3(-\frac{1}{2} - \cos 2\theta)\\
\sin^22\theta + \cos^22\theta = 1$$

Input $\sin 2\theta$ from the first equation into the second, you get

$$3\left(\frac14 + \cos2\theta + \cos^22\theta\right) + \cos^22\theta = 1$$

setting $x=\cos(2\theta)$ means you have a quadratic equation

$$4x^2 + 3x +\frac14 =0$$
which you can solve for $x$. Once you do, you have $\cos2\theta$ and can extract $\theta$ from the equations.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use  [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) to form a Quadratic Equation in $\tan\theta$

and use the range of the [Principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of $\arctan$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sin\pars{2\theta} + \root{3}\cos\pars{2\theta} = -\,{\root{3} \over 2}:
     \ {\large ?}}$

> $$
> \mbox{Note that}\quad\root{3} = \tan\pars{\pi \over 3}
> $$

\begin{align}
-\,{\root{3} \over 2}&
=\sin\pars{2\theta}
+{\sin\pars{\pi/3} \over \cos\pars{\pi/3} }\,\cos\pars{2\theta}
={\sin\pars{2\theta}\cos\pars{\pi/3} + \cos\pars{2\theta}\sin\pars{\pi/3}
  \over \cos\pars{\pi/3}}
\\[3mm]&={\sin\pars{2\theta + \pi/3} \over 1/2}
\quad\imp\quad
\boxed{\ds{\quad\sin\pars{2\theta + {\pi \over 3}} = -\,{\root{3} \over 4}\quad}}
\end{align}

> $$
> 2\theta_{n} + {\pi \over 3} = \arcsin\pars{-\,{\root{3} \over 4}} + 2n\pi\,,\qquad n\in {\mathbb Z}
> $$

$$\color{#66f}{\large%
\theta_{n}=
\underbrace{\quad-\,\half\,\arcsin\pars{{\root{3} \over 4}} - {\pi \over 6}\quad}
_{\color{#000}{\ds{\approx -0.7475}}}\
+\ n\pi\,,
\qquad \color{#000}{n\in {\mathbb Z}}} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Letting $\alpha = 2 \theta$ and dividing each side by $2$, we have $$-\frac {\sqrt 3} {4} = \frac {1} {2} \sin \alpha + \frac {\sqrt 3} {2} \cos \alpha = \sin (\alpha + \frac {\pi} {3}).$$ Hence, we have $\alpha = (\pi) \pm \arcsin \left ( -\frac {\sqrt 3} {4} \right ) - \frac {\pi} {3} + 2 \pi n$ so $$\theta = \frac {1} {2} \arcsin \left ( \frac {\sqrt 3} {4} \right ) - \frac {\pi} {6} + \pi n \qquad \text {and} \qquad \theta = -\frac {1} {2} \arcsin \left ( \frac {\sqrt 3} {4} \right ) + \frac {\pi} {3} + \pi n.$$ For any integer $n$, we have $$\max \theta + \min \theta = 2 \pi n - \frac {\pi} {6}.$$ The ones in the interval $[0, 2 \pi [$ are your solutions.